# Datatables PHP file to exclude certain rows

Tags: php, mysql, json, datatables

I have the following that I'm using with datatables and it works fine to retrieve what I need:

```
$table = 'full_data';

$primaryKey = 'index';

$columns = array(
array( 'db' => 'category',  'dt' => 0 ),
array( 'db' => 'value',  'dt' => 1 ),  
array( 'db' => 'database_percent',     'dt' => 2),
array( 'db' => 'national_percent',     'dt' => 3 ),
array( 'db' => 'index_value',     'dt' => 4 ),
  array( 'db' => 'quadrant',     'dt' => 5 )  
);

$sql_details = array(
'user' => 'root',
'pass' => '*****',
'db'   => 'my_db',
'host' => 'localhost'

);

require( 'ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

What I'd like to do now is exclude rows from what's eventually rendered into JSON by this file. The mySQL query that gets what I want is this:

```
SELECT * FROM  `full_data` WHERE  `category` NOT LIKE  'state'
```

However, I have no idea how to include this in my php file so that only the correct rows are JSON encoded for use in my table. Totally new to using mySQL databases/PHP.

EDIT: Here is my [ssp.class.php](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php) file.

Comment: Impossible to tell what's needed without seeing what your SSP class actually does ...

Comment: @HartmutHolzgraefe Here's the source for my SSP class: https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php

Comment: Is your query = 'state' because you are not adding any "%"s to your like statement?

Comment: What does your db table look like? Cause I see that you have an primary key of index, but then your column is index_value?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are many ways to accomplish this (and sorry for the question with minimal details), but here's what I was able to do to get this to work.

Thanks to @HartmutHolzgraefe suggestion, I looked in my SSP class file and found this:

```
// Main query to actually get the data
    $data = SSP::sql_exec( $db, $bindings,
        "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `".implode("`, `", SSP::pluck($columns, 'db'))."`
         FROM `$table`
         $where
         $order
         $limit"
    );
```

I simply updated the query in here to match the query I needed to exclude those rows. I did have to make a second ssp.class.php file for this, as I use the original in several other places and I needed it as is.

Like I said, I'm sure there's a better way to do this versus having two of these files, but this is the quick "hack" I was able to come up with.